# jQuery string parsing logs a 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mustache

Here's the setup, I have a mustache template stored as a string, like so

```
<div id="one">
    <span>
        <img src="{{foo}}" />
    </span>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <span>
        <img src="{{bar}}" />
    </span>
</div>
```

I've inserted it into the page, all good

But now I need to get a part of that template and re-insert it into the page, the problem is jQuery keeps on logging 404 errors because it's trying to download the image for some reason. (no image pre-loaders or plugins here)

```
var newTemplate = $(Template).find('#two').html();
```

I thought this would just operate on the string, but it seems to be parsing it as actual DOM elements and trying to download the images... here's the error from Chrome

```
GET http://localhost/src/%7B%7Bphoto%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) /src/js/libs/jquery.js:5952
   jQuery.fn.extend.html /src/js/libs/jquery.js:5952
   jQuery.extend.access /src/js/libs/jquery.js:855
   jQuery.fn.extend.html /src/js/libs/jquery.js:5928
   Backbone.View.extend.search /src/js/views/vote.js:39
   jQuery.event.dispatch /src/js/libs/jquery.js:3332
   jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

I've also tried a few variations like

```
var foo = $('<div />').html(Template).find('#isotope').html();
```

and

```
var foo = $('<div />').detach().html(Template).find('#isotope').html();
```

what really bugs me is that this works fine if i write the html i want as a plain string, 
but that defeats the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use separate strings for your templates. As soon as you pass strings to jQuery's `$()` they are turned into DOM elements.

Comment: I ended up just using regex to get the part of the template i wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {foo:'/images/foo.jpg',bar:'/images/bar.jpg'};
var html = $.mustache(Template,data);
var two = html.find('#two');
```

Please read http://zudolab.net/blog/?p=221 (Japanese)